# UK Travel History

Tags: history

I am applying for a family visit visa for my mum to come to the UK. On the visa form, I need to fill in travel history into the UK in the past 10 years. 
My mum has been to the UK many times to visit me. Every time she is here, we go on short holidays to Europe (3-4 days) and then come back into the UK.
Do I need to include all entry and exit dates even for very short trips out of the UK? It looks as if she comes in to the UK and then leaves and then comes in again very frequently.
Please kindly advise. Thank you.

Comment: Any time she enters and leaves the country it is a visit, regardless of duration.

Comment: @MusoniusRufus That question doesn't appear close enough to this one; it hardly even seems vaguely related.

Comment: @MusoniusRufus I read everything again. I still don't understand why you think this is a duplicate.

Comment: The question is _Do I need to include all entry and exit dates even for very short trips out of the UK?_ And the linked question and answer clearly answer that. A visit is a visit regardless of length of stay so yes. You are free and encouraged to provide an answer if you think otherwise.

Comment: @Brenda Pinto Your mother’s travel history looks as if she enters/exits the UK frequently because from your description that’s exactly what she is doing. It shouldn’t matter providing she’s not spending more time in the UK than elsewhere/in her home country. IMHO she should declare all visits that were not legitimate transit visits, this https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/673351/Visit-guidance-v7.0EXT.PDF#page16 indicates UKVI will check her history.

Answer (score 0):

The current visit visa application form only asks for details of the last two visits to the UK, the last two visits to Schengen/USA/Canada and all visits in the last 10 years for other countries.

Comment: @Musonius Rufus https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/apply Just fill out the form with bogus details to see what questions the form asks.

Comment: @Musonius Rufus AFAIK the new form was created in 2016